# How to use dylib in Mac OS X (C++)

Tags: c++, macos, build, load, dylib

I made an application (an executable) calling some dylib successfully. However, the dylib files and the executable are in different directory. I added the directory contains dylib files to the `$PATH` environment variable. However, it still doesn't load. I copy all the dylib files to the executable, the program finally runs. This confirms the dylib files have no problem. However, how can I tell the OS to find it?
In windows, I just need to add the directory path contains dll files to $PATH. What do I need to do for Mac OS X?

Comment: Check dependencies of your app using `otool -L app`. If they are hardcoded as absolute paths then modify them using `install_name_tool -change old new file` to become relative one. After that the linker may find a library in your `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable.

Answer (score 40):

After reading the link that Justin provided, I was successfully able to use the `@executable_path` token to change my dylib install_name to point to the same dir where my executable is located.

> **@executable_path** Absolute paths are annoying. Sometimes you want to embed a framework into an application instead of having to install
>   the framework into /Library or a similar location.
>
> The Mac's solution to this is @executable_path. This is a magic token
>   that, when placed at the beginning of a library's install name, gets
>   expanded to the path of the executable that's loading it, minus the
>   last component. For example, let's say that Bar.app links against
>   Foo.framework. If Bar.app is installed in /Applications,
>   @executable_path will expand to /Applications/Bar.app/Contents/MacOS.
>   If you intend to embed the framework in Contents/Frameworks, then you
>   can just set Foo.framework's install name to
>   @executable_path/../Frameworks/Foo.framework/Versions/A/Foo. The
>   dynamic linker will expand that to
>   /Applications/Bar.app/Contents/MacOS/../Frameworks/Foo.framework/Versions/A/Foo
>   and will find the framework there.
>
> > http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2009-11-06-linking-and-install-names.html

I will demonstrate with an example.

Let's say I have the following executable */opt/local/bin/convert* and its dylibs are in */opt/local/lib*.
 I want to copy it to another dir and have it load its dylibs from the same directory as where I copied the executable.

```
> mkdir ~/tmp/bin
> cp /opt/local/bin/convert ~/tmp/bin
```

Get a list of the executables dylibs

```
> otool -L ~/tmp/bin/convert
~/tmp/bin/convert:
    /opt/local/lib/libtiff.3.dylib (compatibility version 13.0.0, current version 13.5.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 159.1.0)
    /opt/local/lib/libjpeg.8.dylib (compatibility version 12.0.0, current version 12.0.0)
    /opt/local/lib/libfontconfig.1.dylib (compatibility version 6.0.0, current version 6.4.0)
    /opt/local/lib/libiconv.2.dylib (compatibility version 8.0.0, current version 8.1.0)
    /opt/local/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib (compatibility version 15.0.0, current version 15.0.0)
    /opt/local/lib/libexpat.1.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 7.2.0)
    /opt/local/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.6)
    /opt/local/lib/libz.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.2.6)
    ...
```

I only care about the dylibs in the */opt/local/lib* dir, so we pull out only dylibs in */opt*. I want to keep all other dylib references intact especially to */usr/lib/libSystem* stuff.

```
> DYLIBS=`otool -L ~/tmp/bin/convert | grep "/opt" | awk -F' ' '{ print $1 }'`
```

Copy all the dylibs that the executable references to the same dir where the executable has been copied to.

```
> for dylib in $DYLIBS; do cp $dylib ~/tmp/bin/; done;
```

Use the `install_name_tool` to change the install name of all the dylibs we pulled out in the step above, and replace them by prepending the `@executable_path` to the dylib name.  This will make the dynamic linker look for the dylib in the same directory as where the executable is located.

```
> for dylib in $DYLIBS; do install_name_tool -change $dylib @executable_path/`basename $dylib` ~/tmp/bin/convert; done;
```

Confirm that the install names have been changed and that *libSystem* is still pointing to */usr/lib/libSystem*.

```
> otool -L ~/tmp/bin/convert
~/tmp/bin/convert:
    @executable_path/libtiff.3.dylib (compatibility version 13.0.0, current version 13.5.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 159.1.0)
    @executable_path/libjpeg.8.dylib (compatibility version 12.0.0, current version 12.0.0)
    @executable_path/libfontconfig.1.dylib (compatibility version 6.0.0, current version 6.4.0)
    @executable_path/libiconv.2.dylib (compatibility version 8.0.0, current version 8.1.0)
    @executable_path/libfreetype.6.dylib (compatibility version 15.0.0, current version 15.0.0)
    @executable_path/libexpat.1.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 7.2.0)
    @executable_path/libbz2.1.0.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.6)
    @executable_path/libz.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.2.6)
    ...
```

Comment: Note that it appears you have to do this for each library file as well, since they may also contain links to absolute paths

Comment: This whole `install_name_tool` dance must be recursive until you reach the "leaf" lib that depends only on system libs, i.e., things under `/usr/lib` or `/System/Library`.

Answer (score 15):

You need to set the `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable.

From the [dyld man page](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/darwin/reference/manpages/man1/dyld.1.html):

```
      This  is  a  colon  separated  list  of directories that contain libraries. The dynamic linker
      searches these directories before it searches the default locations for libraries.  It  allows
      you to test new versions of existing libraries.

      For  each  library  that  a program uses, the dynamic linker looks for it in each directory in
      DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH in turn. If it still can't find the library,  it  then  searches  DYLD_FALL-
      BACK_FRAMEWORK_PATH and DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH in turn.
```

Comment: thanks! I also found this by google, I did set the DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH, however, it doesn't work, problem is still there! I am so confusing

Comment: Hi, EmeryBerger,is you DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH variable originally empty. mine is. I don't know if this is wrong at the first place.

Comment: But the page in @Justin's answer includes a better solution, which is to compile your code with -rpath pointing to the directory (if that is an option for you).

Comment: I read the document and can't understand, I tried adding -rpath <the dylib path> to the linker flag, it doesn't work, neither adding to compiler flag works... I just wonder why DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH doesn't work for me? Do I need to set anything else?

Comment: How do I load the program? After setting DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH, I just use $./<exec name> to load the program, do I need to type something else? Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps we need more information here - sample code, Makefile / compilation parameters, etc.

Comment: @AlfredZhong Make sure you use `export` when you set DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH . See here for why: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8699244/402807

Answer (score 6):

many ways. maybe this will help:

http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2009-11-06-linking-and-install-names.html

Answer (score 2):

If the dylib is in the place specified by the INSTALL_NAME of the library, it will Just Work*.

Otherwise, you can add the location of the dylib to DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH.  You might want to read the [dyld documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/darwin/reference/manpages/man1/dyld.1.html).

*) to be totally precise, it needs to be at DYLD_ROOT_PATH/INSTALL_NAME, but fussing with DYLD_ROOT_PATH is pretty rare.

Comment: Sorry, what is "INSTALL_NAME of the library"? I add DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH and it doesn't work, so confused.

Comment: You need to export the variable: export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib`