# How does my C program know where to find my binary library?

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use dylib in Mac OS X (C++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4677044/how-to-use-dylib-in-mac-os-x-c)

I have the following files:

- lost.h
- lost.dylib

I am struggling with the concept of how my C program knows where my lost.dylib file lives? At the top of my file I do an include `#include "lost.h"` but how does my program know about my lost.dylib?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At link time it uses a combination of standard directories and user specified directories

[Linker options](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html) has more information. Basically using **-L** option you can specify more directories to search for **dylib** that you are interested in.

If you are using Xcode, [this link has more details](http://www.maximporges.com/2010/02/08/adding-headers-and-external-libraries-to-xcode-projects/)

As far as runtime finding of the dynamic library is concerned. OS X does it a little bit different that other platforms. [OS X embeds an "install name" inside each dynamic library](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?ApplicationLinking). You can use `otool -L` to find the details

Answer (score 1):

When linking, you should specify with the linker options (**-L** for directories, **-l** for libs). Your library should be named liblost.dylib, and the linker option should be **-llost**. (strip the 'lib' preffix and the .dylib extension).

Also, when the binary is compiled, you can use the [`otool`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/darwin/reference/manpages/man1/otool.1.html) command if you want to find out where your executable is searching for the dylib.

And if you want to change that directory, you can use [`install_name_tool`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/darwin/reference/manpages/man1/install_name_tool.1.html).