# pkg-config 0.26 on OS X Lion seems to be ignoring PKG_CONFIG_PATH

Tags: pkg-config

I am using pkg-config 0.26 on OS X Lion.

When I `echo $PKG_CONFIG_PATH`, it seems that the variable is blank.

When I assign into it, e.g. `PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/path/to/my/folder/containing/pc/files`, and then run `pkg-config --list-all`, the `.pc` files in the directory that I ostensibly just added are not found.

I have been side-stepping this issue by soft linking to individual `.pc` files from `/opt/local/share/pkgconfig`, but I would prefer to figure out what the right way is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aha! This works:

`export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/path/to/my/folder/containing/pc/files`

This makes total sense, it's just that I wrote the question before I knew the meaning of the command `export`.

Quoting from [Defining a variable with or without export](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158091/bash-defining-a-variable-with-or-without-export) :

> `export` makes the variable available to subprocesses

And pkgconfig is a subprocess of the shell when it is run.