# Build C++ library on OS X/Mac using Qt

Tags: c++, macos, qt, dll

I have created a C++ library on Windows using Qt and it works well. Now I want to build the same C++ library on OS X/Mac using Qt, and after running the same steps as how I made this C++ library on Windows, I’m not sure which generated files is the library I need on OS X.
On Windows, I can use the library in other C++ project through the following files: .dll, object file library and the header file. I can find the first two files generated in the target folder:

[image]

But on Mac, after checking the same folder I found the generated files as below:

[image]

Which files are the library that I made? And how to use the generated library in other C++ project on OS X?
I try to find some step-by-step guide but with  no luck so far, so if there’s any useful link that will be of help.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The library is

```
libsdk.1.0.0.dylib
```

all other libsdk*.dylib are links to the library (compatibility reasons, some applications look for libsdk.dylib). You use these library as you would use any other dynamic library. Supply the library and the header files to the local path or install them system wide (DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH).

See [How to use dylib in Mac OS X (C++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4677044/how-to-use-dylib-in-mac-os-x-c) for more information.