# OSX terminal app, fails to load dylib file

Tags: macos, terminal, dylib, dyld

I have created a dylib file. Successfully added it to one Terminal(Console based app through Xcode). When I run the app through Xcode they dylib is loaded and all the methods inside it works.

The issue is when I run the Consols App (Unix Executable) it fails to find the dylib and throws the following error.

```
DS-Anoopkumar-v:~ anoopvaidya$ /Users/anoopvaidya/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Worker-dfytfqadwmzqmvesrzqeartqcggx/Build/Products/Debug/Worker; exit; dyld: Library not loaded: @executable_path/../libDownloader.dyli
Referenced from: /Users/anoopvaidya/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Worker-dfytfqadwmzqmvesrzqeartqcggx/Build/Products/Debug/Worker
Reason: image not found Trace/BPT trap: 5 logout

[Process completed]
```

Please tell me what I am missing here, any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: OK, so does `libDownloader.dylib` exist in the expected directory (which as you can see is the parent directory of the executable)?

Comment: @trojanfoe: I Solved this. I found the issue, posting it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

In Build Setting's "Dynamic Library Install Name" I replaced "@executable_path/.../Framework/libILDownloader.dylib" with "@executable_path/libILDownloader.dylib" and it worked.

[image]

Thanks to this answer [How to use dylib in Mac OS X (C++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4677044/how-to-use-dylib-in-mac-os-x-c), that helped me to understand

Comment: That's not the whole story though is it.  Firstly you must have a script that is copying `libILDownloader.dylib` to the same folder as the executable, as by default each Xcode target builds into a separate folder.  Secondly when it comes to release/install, the `.dylib` probably wants to live in `/usr/local/lib`, so you should use different settings for Debug and Release builds.  It's unusual (and fiddly) to have a command line executable that requires a 3rd-party `.dylib` to be installed in order to work, so you are probably better off statically linking in this library.