# How can I easily redistribute dylib in MacOS?

Tags: macos, dylib, otool, install-name-tool

I would like to distribute my application.  However, it is full of dylibs all from different locations.  I would like to just copy them to the Resources/lib directory and set my LD_LIBRARY_PATH to point to it with a startup shell script, just like I do in Linux after I clear the rpath with chrpath.  Currently, I am struggling with otool / install_name_tool and I don't seem to be able to change the 'name' property of the dylib.

Comment: Why not leave them in Resources where they will be found automatically at load time?

Comment: Sorry.  I am not familiar with MacOS.  You mean that if I leave them in Contents/Resources (or is it Contents/Resources/lib?) they will be found automatically, regardless of install name or rpath?

Comment: Did you try searching? I found this immediately: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4677044/how-to-use-dylib-in-mac-os-x-c