# How do you include/link libraries to an executable file Eclipse c++

Tags: c++, eclipse-cdt, sdl-2, sdl-image

I am trying to distribute an executable file from a c++ project I made in eclipse. The problem is, it uses the SDL2 and SDL2 Image libraries which works fine on my computer since they are downloaded already, but when I try to run it on another computer I get an error message saying:

```
dyld[16619]: Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libSDL2-2.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/garrettmurray/Downloads/Morph Bunny-2/Morph Bunny
  Reason: tried: '/opt/local/lib/libSDL2-2.0.0.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libSDL2-2.0.0.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libSDL2-2.0.0.dylib' (no such file)
zsh: abort      /Users/garrettmurray/Downloads/Morph\ Bunny-2/Morph\ Bunny
```

Is there any way to include them into the executable, or do they need to be downloaded as well and if so how do you link them to the executable?

Comment: Usually, you ship the executable with all the dependencies (in case of shared libraries). But if the libraries are static libraries, then you don't need to ship the dependencies - the libraries are included within the executable.

Comment: SDL2 and SDL Image are shared libraries so I need to ship them with the executable, but I can't figure out how to link them together so that the executable can access them.

Comment: Or you can install the libraries in another system.

Comment: The usual way to do this is to place the libraries at a known place *relatively* to the executable, and use rpath to make the executable find them. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4677044/how-to-use-dylib-in-mac-os-x-c or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33991581/install-name-tool-to-update-a-executable-to-search-for-dylib-in-mac-os-x